# Aggregating a Map object within another Object

Tags: java, dictionary

Edited version! From a PC instead of my phone. 
I have a Class defined with following attributes:

Here is the code I have for a sample Map without being part of another class:

```
    List<Map<String,Long>> amountList = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Long> amountMap = new HashMap<>();

    for(int i=0; i<2;i++ ) {
        amountMap.put("AMOUNT1", 12L);
        amountMap.put("AMOUNT2", 10L);
        amountMap.put("AMOUNT3", 10L);
        amountMap.put("AMOUNT4", 12L);
        amountMap.put("AMOUNT5", 10L);
        amountList.add(amountMap);
    }

    Map<String, Long> collectset = amountList.stream()
            .flatMap(entry -> entry.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, Long::sum));

    for (String str : collectset.keySet()){
        System.out.println( "output: " + str + " -> " + collectset.get(str));
    }
```

I need a result from this where the output is just as below:

```
output: AMOUNT3 -> 20
output: AMOUNT2 -> 20
output: AMOUNT1 -> 24
output: AMOUNT5 -> 20
output: AMOUNT4 -> 24
```

What I get as a result of the code above is that the values are repeating twice. 
Is there a way to only output the Sum equivalent once. For instance, if the loop is changed to produce 5 Maps - I see the output printed 5 times.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: I have added a code snippet of what I have tried. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make an info object containing three strings and use that as your key value (don't forget to override hashCode if needed). Or simply use a format (such as CSV) to concatinate your strings together and then use that string as a key.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the issue. There was a for loop just before the Stream implementation which caused to print the output based on how many times I was looping through the loop.

Here is the updated code:

```
    List<Map<String,Long>> countList = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Long> countMap = new HashMap<>();

    Random random = new Random();

    for(int i=0; i<500;i++ ) {
        countMap.put("COUNT" + random.nextInt(10), 12L);
        countMap.put("COUNT" + random.nextInt(10), 10L);
        countMap.put("COUNT" + random.nextInt(10), 10L);
        countMap.put("COUNT" + random.nextInt(10), 12L);
        countMap.put("COUNT" + random.nextInt(10), 10L);
        countList.add(countMap);
    }

    Map<String, Long> collectset = countList.stream()
            .flatMap(entry -> entry.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, Long::sum));

    System.out.println( "CollectSet Size: " + collectset.size());
```